# Cauchy product of uniformly convergent power series uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\sum_{1}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty} b_nz^n$ be power series with the radius of convergence $2$. Then is the Cauchy product of these two power series also uniformly convergent for any $\mid z \mid \leq r<2$? I know that the Cauchy product converges pointwise and absolutely. However I am not so sure about the uniform convergence of the cauchy product.

Comment: The coefficient of the cauchy product is given by sums of $a_n$ and $b_n$. So that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Radius convergence 2 and use Mertens theorem.

Comment: For any $ |z|=r<2$, Cauchy product is convergent by Mertens theorem. What does it mean?

Comment: It means pointwise convergence at first.

Comment: However I cannot guarantee the uniform convergence

Comment: Check property of power series? When does it uniformly convegent?

Comment: Oh....I see. Thank you.

Comment: [Some examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675006/148510).  The Cauchy product radius is always greater than or equal to the smaller of the radii for $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$.